CMake - Proper way to link a library
I have a function add_lib that receives a target as an argument.
Then, for the given target, it searches for boost and includes the library for that target.
 find_package(Boost COMPONENTS chrono atomic system thread serialization regex iostreams REQUIRED)
        if(Boost_FOUND)
            target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
            link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
            target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
            target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC HAVE_BOOST)

The problem is that this approach performs find_package more than once, as this is done for each target that it invokes this function.
This invocation is essentially the FindBoost function (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html). What is the correct way to transform this program, in order to have a global definition of boost, and not linked for each target?
The function exists in a .cmake file, while calls to this function happen at individual CMakeLists.txt files.
EDIT: The code for the function called:
function(add_lib TARGET_NAMES)
    foreach(TARGET_NAME ${TARGET_NAMES})
        # Find Boost
        find_package(Boost COMPONENTS chrono atomic system thread serialization regex iostreams REQUIRED)

        if(Boost_FOUND)
            # Include directories
            target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

            # Link directories
            link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

            # Link libraries
            target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

            # Add a compile definition
            target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC HAVE_BOOST)
        else()
            message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost not found. Please install Boost.")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()


Call find_package once at the top level and then everybody calls the function that checks if(Boost_FOUND)?  I'm pretty sure that variable will be in scope everywhere.

@StephenNewell How do I call it? This function exists in a .cmake file, while the calls to this function (where the target parameters) are passed, happen in individual CMakeLists.txt files, scattered all over the place. Where does the call have to happen exactly?

You copy and paste the find_package line into your top level CMakeLists.txt, then delete it from the function. Shouldn't have to change the function or calls at all.  If that doesn't do it, give us an actual [mcve] to look at.

I did that but then Boost_FOUND is not true in the .cmake file.

[Edit] your question with a [mcve].

Actually, I declared it higher in the top level CMakeLists.txt file and it works! However, now since many targets call this function as well, isn't it exactly the same thing? Linking many times, that is....

If you have N targets that require against boost, then you need to link N times.  Is your concern about linking or calling find_package multiple times, since your question seems more concerned with the latter.

Yes, this is exactly my concern! I don't want this to happen multiple times, as now it finds boost for many different targets.

Okay, for the third time, [edit] your question with a [mcve].  Not a snippet of part of your function, but something that shows the full function implementation and how it's called, including with the change I suggested earlier that you said works.
